# Why .Net API controller parses string to int 0 for integer property instead of bad request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a model class that has an integer property

```
public class Foo 
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public int Type {get; set;}
}
```

Type is an optional property, so when the value is not provided it will be 0, and based on that I can assign the default value.

But the issue is, when sending the string value to Type, it will parse that to int 0 instead of returning a bad request.

Ex:

```
{
  "Name": "my name",
  "Type: "This is invalid"
}
```

I tried adding validation, but the problem is when it reaches validation, the Type is equal to 0.

So I cannot differentiate the above request and the below request.

```
 {
     "Name": "my name"
 }
```

All I want is to return the bad request for the first request.

Comment: Are you sure you are interested in "why" and not in how to make it work the way you need it to work?

Comment: That doesn't work either. when it is nullable int, the Type would be null in both cases.

Comment: Can I ask what dotnet version you are using? On dotnet 6, it would return a bad response if type is an uncastable string. Same on dotnet 5

Comment: I am using .Net 4.7, yes it is working in .Net Core

Comment: I might be overcomplicating things, but I think [custom converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1) might help you. You should be able to write one that throws if supplied string cannot be parsed as a number.